# Detect outerHeight() of element with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, dom-manipulation

I'm trying to detect the height of an element that will change depending on data from a database.

I have used .outerHeight successfully before but can't do this on an element that contains data from a ng-repeat.

Is there a way to do this once the data has populated the angular element or is there another method of detecting this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to create an attribute directive and put it on the ng-repeat.

```
<div ng-repeat="whatever in items" outer-height></div>
```

The directive will have a link function which happens after it has compiled.

```
app.directive('outerHeight', function(){
  return{
    restrict:'A',
    link: function(scope, element){
       //using outerHeight() assumes you have jQuery
       //use Asok's method in comments if not using jQuery
       console.log(element.outerHeight()); 
    }
  };
});
```

Here's a Plnkr which will log the outerHeight to console: http://plnkr.co/edit/AdGpnzJilW2179Ybuurk?p=preview

**Note** You will need to use a `$watch` and get a new height if data changes.

Comment: +1, Without jQuery you should be able to fall back on `angular.element`, `angular.element(element).prop('offsetHeight'));` should give you the same result. `angular.element` does *NOT* support `outerHeight()` and `height()`

Comment: I ran a couple tests with padding and margins set and both gave the same results

Comment: @Asok thanks, that's perfect. I only used outerHeight because that's what Paul used but I added a note.

Comment: Of course, I fully suspect most will use JQuery anyway since it is such a popular framework. I just wanted to add an alternative to build upon your answer.