# Find the biggest height of a div in ng-repeat

Tags: css, angularjs, dom

I have a set of data which is an array of objects. Some objects have more data than the other. But each object will display in each col-md-4 div. Therefore, the height of each div will be different based on how much data an object has.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-12 eventlog-info-container">
  <div class="row eventlogs-single-container">
    <div class="col-md-4 eventlog-1-container" ng-repeat="record in records track by $index">
        <h4>Event Log {{$index}}</h4>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in record">{{::key}}: {{::value}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My question is after ng-repeat, I want to find the biggest height of the element. And then apply the biggest height to each of the element using ng-style.

I have an idea to approach that using JQuery. However, I want to use Angular to do that? Any suggestion? Anuglar is not good for DOM manipulation?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Yes, Angular was not born for DOM manipulation, so you should go with jQuery. However, if you want to do it in an angular-way, you should wrap your code in a directive.

Comment: I understand. And @Rkhayat gave me a good start point. However, I need to somehow return all the height and then manipulate them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After I did some research yesterday. I found an open source angular directive to solve my problem -  [angularJS Vertilize Directive](http://sixthdim.github.io/angular-vertilize/) An AngularJS directive to vertically equalize a group of elements with varying heights. In other words, it dynamically makes a group of elements the same height. Thank you Chris Collins who made this directive.

```
<div vertilize-container class="row">
  <div ng-repeat="col in columns" class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="well">
      <div vertilize>
       <h3>{{ col.title }}</h3>
       <p>{{ col.body }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The best solution I found. I am using it for an ng-repeat on components and it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887043/detect-outerheight-of-element-with-ng-repeat) answer should get you started on the right path.

```
<div class="col-md-12 eventlog-info-container">
  <div class="row eventlogs-single-container">
    <div class="col-md-4 eventlog-1-container" ng-repeat="record in records track by $index">
        <h4>Event Log {{$index}}</h4>
        <ul>
            <li outer-height ng-repeat="(key, value) in record">{{::key}}: {{::value}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


app.directive('outerHeight', function(){
  return{
    restrict:'A',
    link: function(scope, element){
       //using outerHeight() assumes you have jQuery
       // if not using jQuery
       console.log(element.outerHeight()); 

    }
  };
});
```

Comment: That's what I'm talking about. Thanks for your quick response, bro.

Comment: Thank you advanced first, I will try it and let you know.

Comment: Your answer only gives me how to get the value of one particular height. But I need to get the biggest one and apply the height again. Any thought? It's a good direction to start.

Comment: @Rkhayat check out my answer.