# ng-repeat bootstrap columns with the same hight

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using ng-repeat to spawn multiple rows each with two sections. I do not know how many sections I have in total or how much content is in each section.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6" ng-repeat="(key, values) in additionalDetails">
    <h3>{{key}}</h3>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in values">{{value}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want all the sections on the same row to be the same height but obviously the content in the row above can throw the alignment off. I know I can use the below but I can't figure out how?

```
<div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
```

Comment: This post might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31539991/find-the-biggest-height-of-a-div-in-ng-repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use an **Angular.js directive** that *watches the heights of all your columns*, and ensures that they remain the same height. I've included a little directive written by [officert](https://github.com/officert) for this purpose. Add the directive to each element that you want to be the same size, and your selected columns will be resized to match the **tallest** column:

**Usage Example**

```
<div class="question-list" equal-heights=".question" equal-heights-items="questions">
  <div class="question col-md-3" ng-repeat="question in questions">
     <h4>{{ question.question }}</h4>
     <p ng-bind-html="question.answer"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Directive:**

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('equalHeights', [
  '$timeout',
  function($timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        equalHeightsItems: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        var selector = attrs.equalHeights;

        scope.$watch('equalHeightsItems', function(newVal) {
          if (newVal && newVal.length) {
            $timeout(function() {
              equalize();
            });
          }
        });

        function equalize() {
          var height = 0;

          var $elements = element.find(selector);

          _.each($elements, function(el) {
            var $el = angular.element(el);
            var elHeight = $el.outerHeight();

            if (elHeight > height) height = elHeight;
          });

          $elements.height(height);
        }
      }
    };
  }
]);
```